# React Native App causing phone to heat up extensively

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, mobile-development

I have a react native app that worked seamlessly fine on android and ios a few weeks ago (no lags or slow downs)

Until recently, I started noticing that mostly ios devices complain that their phones heat up immediately they enter into my app

Has anyone experienced such an issue before?, and If so what to do to fix it, i am memorizing most components and am caching some images that will render in my app multiple times as optimization efforts but the stats remain the same

Below are some of the stats for the app from Xcode, in my opinion, I don't think it's enough to cause heating

[Memory Usage from Xcode profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzdNm.png)

[More memory usage from Xcode run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuZNJ.png)

[CPU Usage from Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhyht.png)

[Cpu Usage details from profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKGYU.png)

[Image showing next process causing cpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnFDX.png)

[Run loop function causing the High CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxW9g.png)

Comment: Memory usage won't typically cause the device to heat up - try using the Time Profiler in Xcode instead to see what the CPU is doing.  It's usually Javascript running too ofrten that causes an issue like this.

Comment: Thanks @Abe, I have edited the question to include some images that were taken from the profiler, seems to be a file called 

RCTCxxBridge in the runLoop function that is causing it, I still don't know what to do though to stop it or where that particular function is too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I solved this issue, there were a number of reasons why it started

- I had an animation running in the background because a useEffect function cleanup did not stop the animation when navigating away from the screen
- I had numerous useFocusEffect without a React.useCallback function so the useFocusEffect would have had a cleanup function through the React.useCallback
- Some useEffect functions had no cleanup- During the time I was facing the issue, I changed ALL (about 420 in total) of my components and screens from normal components to memoized (React.memo) which means that all my components were being stored in memory as soon as they rendered - which is bad because it obviously causes high RAM usage, so we had to delete those - and only use them on about 2 components that rendered multiple times and had costly computations that didn't need to run every time they rendered

After doing all of that, my CPU and memory usage drastically reduced to what it is below (link)

[New CPU and memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzZvU.png)